# how to create loop function in schema with google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, schema.org, json-ld

```
          "name":"{{post eletitle}}",
          "url":"{{Page URL}}",
          "sameAs":[],
          "dateCreated":["{{post modified time}}"],
          "image":
            {
              "width":"{{post image width}}",
              "height":"{{post image height}}",
              "url":"{{post image}}",
              "@context":"http://schema.org",
              "@type":"ImageObject"
            },
          "description":"{{post description}}",
          "keywords":"master movie rating, Tamil Movie, tamil movie box office report", 
          
"director":[
  {
    "url":"{{li.movie-director-url}}",
    "name":"{{li.movie-director-name}}",
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"Person" 
  },
  {
    "url":"{{li.movie-director-url}}",
    "name":"{{li.movie-director-name}}",
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"Person" 
  },],
"actor":[ 
  {
  "url":"{{a.movie-cast-url}}",
  "name":"{{span.movie-cast-name}}",
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"Person"
  },
  {
  "url":"{{a.movie-cast-url}}",
  "name":"{{span.movie-cast-name}}",
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"Person"
  },
  {
  "url":"{{a.movie-cast-url}}",
  "name":"{{span.movie-cast-name}}",
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"Person"
  },
  {
  "url":"{{a.movie-cast-url}}",
  "name":"{{span.movie-cast-name}}",
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"Person"
  },],
"@context":"http://schema.org",
"@type":"Movie"
};
```

i create schema for movie with google tag manager. actor and director data add with dom css selector in google tag manager.

class variable is a.movie-cast-url and a.movie-cast-url-name how add many actor loop data in this script function? tag manager get same value in all loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, deploying schema through GTM is not proper. SEO should have no relation to GTM. Also, schema usually inflates the limited GTM size pretty rapidly. Deployment of schema through GTM should be treated a hotfix or a test. Very temporary. If the current size of GTM allows it.

Now to your question... While you can theoretically do what you're aiming through GTM variables, it would be a pretty unreliable, dirty and laborious piece of implementation, branching into many awkward GTM variables created just for this tag, thus inflating the container size and complexity even more. I usually avoid declaring GTM variables for the sake of one tag. I would suggest writing a custom JS variable that would generate a JS object, parsing the page as you see fit. Then just return it and use that one variable in your custom HTML without hardcoding anything but `<script type="application/ld+json"></script>` in it.

In case you don't have solid knowledge of JS... Well, this is not a task done without JS knowledge. Variables won't save you here, even in the multiple variables route, you will have to write code in them for this particular case. And it will be much harder than keeping all in one scope.

Comment: no bro, i add start and end script tag <script type="application/ld+json"></script>. but my question is how to create loop function inside the json script. its possible or not. see my webpage for reference https://cinema.mrpuyal.com/movie/master-2021/

Comment: you don't need to do it in a json script. You insert your CJS variable in it like so: `<script type="application/ld+json">{{Your JS variable name goes here}}</script>` And in that variable, you do all the parsing in the world and return the object.

Comment: now i add class="name-{counter}" for each actor class name and create each property dom css selector then add it in the script. example i crate 10 actors property "actor":[ 
  "url":"{{a.movie-cast-url-0}}", "url":"{{a.movie-cast-url-1}}", ect.., if movie actor is 4 the 5 value is not hide its show null.  https://ibb.co/kBJPftF. how to hide for property is empty or how to generate loop function.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do now and I'm saying that you should delete all your code and start over, keeping all parsing logic in one place and never ever modifying DOM.

Comment: how is? i am beginner for java script . please tell some example bro

Comment: oooh, well, as I said, you have to know JS. If you're not able to generate the JSON you need from your browser console, then you pretty much don't have a choice but either learn JS, or ask someone else to write the code for you.

Comment: yes i seeing lots of code in stack overflow and other website. i am trying to add my script its not working. so i finally decide to post my question and ask help for community members to write code for me.

Comment: This not a trivial piece of code. This code will have to have real maintenance and testing. It looks like the scope of the work here is way beyond community answers. We here normally help programmers, not do their job for them. I suggest you relay to your company that they need to hire someone to help them with this. Typically either an implementation specialist or a JS developer.

Comment: no bro, i seen lots of website nobody to generated loop inside the json script. so i asking to expert its possible or not? its possible how to insert inside the script or other method for some example. thats all...

Comment: I never suggested generating loops in json scripts. And it's not needed. I'll explain again: you use a custom JS variable's value as a content for your json script. In that variable, you iterate through your DOM and build the json payload. That it. Simple and elegant.